# Modulo operator and divide operator

Tags: algorithm, math, modulo

Two numbers A and B given to us.

It is given that A is exactly divisible by B.

I need to calculate `(A/B)%MOD.`

We only know two things `A%MOD, B`. How can we calculate this from above two things.

**REAL PROBLEM**

num = `(1*2*3.....*262143)%MOD`, is known to us.

Now, my task is to calculate `(2*3*4*...*262144)%MOD`, then `(3*4*5*....*262145)%MOD`, so on.

where, `MOD = 1000000009`.

**UPDATED :-**

```
A = (2*3*4)%7 = ( 2%7 * 3%7 * 4%7)%7 = 3
B = ( (A*(5%7))%7 )/(2%7) = 0 .......................**THAT IS WRONG, ANSWER SHOULD BE 4**
```

Comment: `(1*anything)%MOD == (anything)%MOD`

Comment: @halex Sorry I wrote wrong equation. Please check again, I updated that.

Comment: Is 262143 factorial = A/B?  What are the values of A%MOD and B?

Comment: A = 262143!, then we need to slide this window by one, means, now I want calculate 262144!, then 262145!/2!, so on.. I think you understand my actual problem.

Comment: Calculation in your last update is incorrect. `(3*(5%7)%7)/(2%7)=1/(2%7)=1*(4%7)=4%7=4`

Comment: @icepack how you wrote 1/(2%7) == 1*(4%7) ?

Comment: Division in a finite field (i.e. operations in modulo) is a multiplication by inverse. Inverse of `x` is `y` for which the following holds: `x * y = 1 mod Z` (Z is your MOD). `2 * 4 = 1 mod 7 `therefore 4 is an inverse of 2 and `1 / 2 = 1 * 4 mod 7 = 4`

Answer (score 3):

Since `1000000009` is prime, the problem is easy. You need to use [modular multiplicative inverses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse).

```
(A / B) % MOD = ((A % MOD) * (B^-1 % MOD)) % MOD
```

You can use [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) for this, which says that, if `p` is prime, then

```
a^(p - 1) % p = 1,
```

which leads to

```
(a * a^(p - 2)) % p = 1,
```

meaning

```
a^(p - 2)
```

is the modular inverse of `a` mod `p`.

```
A = (2 * 3 * 4 * ... * 262144) % MOD
B = (3 * 4 * 5 * ... * 262145) % MOD
  = (A * (2^1000000007 % MOD) * (262145 % MOD)) % MOD
```

Comment: @IVIad  Your example is not clear to me. `(A * (2^1000000007 % MOD) * (262145 % MOD)) % MOD` I thing something wrong in this.

Comment: Its a request to you to please explain above. My doubt is from where `2^1000000007` comes ?

Comment: According to my understanding, B should be, 
`B = (  ( ( A * ( 2^-1 % MOD ) ) % MOD ) * ( 262145 % MOD ) ) % MOD`. Please correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: @devnull - your are correct. However, for `p` prime, the inverse of **any** `a` is `a^-1 = a^(p - 2)`. `p` in your case is `1000000009`, which is `1000000007` if you subtract 2, which is what I did.

Comment: Means 3^-1 comes, it would be 3^1000000007 ? and second question, how can we calculate (2^1000000007 % MOD), (3^1000000007 % MOD)...so on ?

Comment: @devnull Yes, like that. 3^1000000007, 4^1000000007 etc. To calculate these efficiently you can use exponentiation by squaring: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Answer (score -1):

> `(x * y) % mod = (x % mod) * (y % mod)`

Given this identity, you can easily find the answer:

> A = (1*2*3.....*262143)%MOD= (1 % MOD * 2 % MOD *3.....*262143 % MOD)
>
> B = (2*3.....*262144)%MOD= (2 % MOD *3.....*262144 % MOD)
>
> B = A * (262144 % MOD) = (A * 262144) % MOD.

Comment: @devnull exactly the same way

Comment: For calculating (3*4*....*262145)%MOD, we need to remove 2, and add 262145, from (2*3*4*...*262144)%MOD. But you add 262145 only. What about removing of 2 ?

Comment: @devnull divide by 2 % MOD

Comment: But A, or any num,ber may be overflow, so you need to take MOD again after multiplying them, `(x * y) % mod = ((x % mod) * (y % mod))%MOD` Please check.

Comment: @devnull Of course. You may need to apply modulo operator several times, it's not a problem

Comment: Please check my example, in updated section. If wrong please correct me.

Comment: -1: you cannot use division with modulo. `(a / b) % c != (a % c) / (b % c)`.

Comment: @IVlad Division is a multiplication with the inverse in a finite field. That's a pretty known definition; you can find it, for example, here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field_arithmetic

Comment: I know that, but your comment is not clear that you mean multiplication with the inverse, and neither is your answer. `divide by 2 % MOD` implies `something / (2 % MOD)`. You should make your suggestion clearer IMO.

Comment: @IVlad My answer is perfectly clear in that aspect. If you need a refinement of basic math definitions, it has nothing to do with this answer.